# yii, How To Change The Text Color On A Cmenu

Tags: php, css, yii

im trying to find where is the class css that contains the color of this text..

the text if in the menu that gii generates by default on right next to the CListView.. the color is blue but i would like to change it to white for my custom theme, so where can i find this and please tell me if i can set its setting just for this action, i posted the same question on yii forum [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/49276-how-to-change-the-text-color-on-a-cmenu/page__p__229842__fromsearch__1#entry229842), but noone answers.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just add into the selector a class and you can make style for it. I'm not sure what you were trying to do, just look at following example

Setup

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('site/index'),'linkOptions' => array('class'=>'anchor-link')),
        array('label'=>'Products', 'url'=>array('product/index'), 'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'New Arrivals', 'url'=>array('product/new', 'tag'=>'new'),'linkOptions' => array('class'=>'anchor-link')),
            array('label'=>'Most Popular', 'url'=>array('product/index', 'tag'=>'popular'),'linkOptions' => array('class'=>'anchor-link')),
        )),
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'menu-container-class'),
    'activeCssClass' => 'active-class',
    'itemCssClass' => 'item-class',
    'submenuHtmlOptions' => array('class'=>'sub-menu-class')
));
```

Result

```
<ul id="yw0" class="menu-container-class">
    <li class="item-class"><a href="/khucholon/site/index.html" class="anchor-link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item-class"><a href="/khucholon/product/index.html">Products</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-class">
            <li class="item-class"><a href="/khucholon/product/new.html?tag=new">New Arrivals</a></li>
            <li class="item-class"><a href="/khucholon/product/index.html?tag=popular">Most Popular</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-class"><a href="/khucholon/site/login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.item-class a{color:red}
```

or you can use and custom yourself with some of the pseudo-classes

```
a.anchor-link:link, a.anchor-link:active, a.anchor-link:hover, a.anchor-link:visited{
color:red
}
```

Almost you can set css for the node level what you want by using following options:

`linkOptions` (for inmost link)

`htmlOptions`, `activeCssClass`, `itemCssClass`, `submenuHtmlOptions`, `firstItemCssClass`

See more
[Yii CMenu](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your own class to the menu with htmlOptions and use that css class to style as per your need.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'mynav'),
```

And in your css

```
.mynav{
color:red
}
```

Comment: when i saw what you told me, i saw the htmlOptions comes with a default class called 'operations', i just added color:black in that class on my main.css and still no change

Comment: Can you try by adding your own class just like the way I mentioned? I am not sure but changing it in the default may get overridden or there may be other classes styling it too. Juts try it this way and let me know.